# add path to AssemblySearchPaths in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I have a bunch of csproj-files for which I want to add a path to search for assembly-references using the `AssemblySearchPaths`. As they are many project-files  I wanted to do this only once for all using a `Dirtector.Build.Props` in the parent-directory of all my projects.

This is my `Directory.Build.props`:

```
<Project>
    <Choose>
        <When Condition="$(JenkinsBuild)== 'true'">
            <PropertyGroup>
                <AssemblySearchPaths>
                   C:\lib; $(AssemblySearchPaths)
                </AssemblySearchPaths>
            </PropertyGroup>
        </When>
    </Choose>
</Project>
```

When I compile my solution using `MSBuild`, no reference can be found, not even those from `System`.

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019) I got this:

> Directory.Build.props is imported very early in Microsoft.Common.props, and properties defined later are unavailable to it. So, avoid referring to properties that are not yet defined (and will evaluate to empty).

So I assume `AssemblySearchPaths` is just undefined the time the `Directory.Builds.props` is invoked.

Is there any other opportunity to add a path to the list of paths to search for assemblies for many projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it´s so simple. Instead of messing around with the `AssemblySearchPath` I can simply add the path directly to the call to MSBUild as shown [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ab278aab-7c15-48d0-8d9f-1647f1d47029/setting-assemblysearchpaths-during-build?forum=tfsbuild):

```
msbuild MySolution.sln -property:ReferencePath=C:/lib
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem, hardcoding is a working solution.
Simply copy these paths from Microsoft.Common.targets as following:

```
  <AssemblySearchPaths>
    {CandidateAssemblyFiles};
    $(ReferencePath);
    {HintPathFromItem};
    {TargetFrameworkDirectory};
    {Registry:$(FrameworkRegistryBase),$(TargetFrameworkVersion),$(AssemblyFoldersSuffix)$(AssemblyFoldersExConditions)};
    {AssemblyFolders};
    {GAC};
    {RawFileName};
    $(OutputPath);
    HardcodedPath;
    AndHardcodedPath;
    AndMoreHardcodedPath
  </AssemblySearchPaths>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just ran into the same issue while migrating a rather large solution from old project format to new one. We are still realying on some legacy components which are installed into the GAC on developer machines, and published side by side with the application with `Copy Local = True`.

My solution was to use the `Directory.Build.targets` file over the `props`. At first glance it seems to work just fine, however I don't exactly know when it will get imported by the build system, as it has to targets, only acts like a `props` file.